# Tooltip issue with two data sources in d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a d3 chart which is generated from some json that is, in turn, generated by php.  All of that works well -- the php correctly formats the json and the chart displays properly.  It can be seen [here](http://www.matthewedavis.net/Magdalene_playtext/mary_magdalene_chart.php), and I'm including the full code for the javascript portion below:

```
            var margin = {top: 50, right: 150, bottom: 50, left: 150},
            w = 2500 - margin.left - margin.right,
            h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            
        
var json = <?php echo $json; ?>;

console.log(json);

d3.json("MM_chart.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) throw error;

           var items = json.items;

           var locations = json.locations;

           var directions = json.stage_directions;

           console.log(items);
           console.log(locations);
           console.log(directions);

            var stage_directions = ([44, 49, 114, 140, 209, 217, 249, 257, 265, 277, 305, 334, 358, 381, 398, 409, 440, 470, 491, 547, 555, 564, 572, 587, 614, 630, 640, 691, 704, 725, 743, 775, 793, 818, 823, 841, 845, 868, 872, 888, 902, 910, 920, 925, 963, 993, 1005, 1023, 1031, 1047, 1061, 1096, 1125, 1133, 1143, 1178, 1210, 1228, 1281, 1293, 1336, 1349, 1376, 1395, 1439, 1446, 1454, 1538, 1554, 1562, 1578, 1598, 1610, 1618, 1642, 1646, 1716, 1725, 1743, 1781, 1791, 1797, 1843, 1863, 1887, 1915, 1923, 1939 ,1972, 1989, 2019, 2031, 2039, 2045, 2073, 2085, 2101, 2123]);

            var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, 2200])
            .range([0, w]);

            var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(locations.map(function(d) {return d["location"];})) 
            .rangeBands([0, h]);

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");
            
            var tip = d3.tip()
            .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
            .offset([-10, 0])
            .html(function(d, i) {return console.log(d.line_text) + "<strong>(" + d.starting_line + ")</strong> <i>" + d.character + "</i>: " + d.line_text;});

            var stage_tip = d3.tip()
            .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
            .offset([-10, 0])
            .html(function(d, i) {return console.log(d.direction_text) + "<strong>(" + d.line_after + ") s.d.</strong> <i>" + d.direction_text;});

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


            svg.append("text") 
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2) + " ," + (h + margin.bottom - 5) +")")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Line Number");

            var stage_bars = svg.selectAll(".stage_bar")
                .data(directions)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("class", "overlay")
                .attr("class", function(d, i) {return "stage_bar " + d.direction_text;})
                .attr("x", function(d, i) {return d.line_after;})
                .attr("width", 1)
                .attr("height", h)
                .style("fill", "black")
                .style("opacity",0.3)
                .call(stage_tip)
                .on('mouseover', stage_tip.show)
                .on('mouseout',stage_tip.hide);

            svg.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "overlay")
            .attr("x",1)
            .attr("width", 1133)
            .attr("height", h)
            .style ("fill", "red")
            .style ("opacity", 0.1);

            svg.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "overlay")
            .attr("x",1133)
            .attr("width", 857)
            .attr("height", h)
            .style ("fill", "yellow")
            .style ("opacity", 0.1);

            svg.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "overlay")
            .attr("x",1990)
            .attr("width", 134)
            .attr("height", h)
            .style ("fill", "green")
            .style ("opacity", 0.1);

          svg.append("rect")
          .attr("class", "overlay")
          .attr("x",5)
          .attr("y", 10)
          .attr("width", 485)
          .attr("height", 155)
          .style ("fill", "aliceblue")
//              .style ("opacity", 0.1);

            svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

            svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            //.call(bars);  

            var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(items)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", function(d, i) {return "bar " + d.character;})
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {return d.starting_line;})
            .attr("y", function(d, i) {return y(d.location);})
            .attr("width", function(d, i) {return d.duration;})
            .attr("height", 15)
            .style("fill", function(d,i) {return "#" + d.color;})
            .call(tip)
            .on('mouseover', tip.show)
            .on('mouseout', tip.hide);


                   var listCharacters = d3.set(items.map(function(d) {return d.character})).values();

                   listColors = [];

                   listPositions = [];

                   for (l = 0; l < listCharacters.length; l++) {
                       for (var key in items) {
                           if (listCharacters[l] === items[key].character) {
                               if (listColors.indexOf(items[key].color) > -1) {} else {
                                   listColors.push(items[key].color);
                                   var xlegend = (Math.floor(l / 10) * 100);
                                   var ycounter;
                                   var ylegend;
                                   var oldxlegend;

                                   if (l === 0) {
                                       ycounter = 1;
                                   }

                                   if (ycounter < 10) {
                                       listPositions.push(ycounter * 15);
                                       ycounter++;
                                   } else {
                                       listPositions.push(ycounter * 15);
                                       ycounter = 1;
                                   }

                               }
                           } else {}
                       }
                   }


console.log(listCharacters);
console.log(listColors);
console.log(listPositions);

            var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
            .data(listCharacters)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + (Math.floor(i / 10)  * 105) + ", " + listPositions[i] + ")"; })

            legend.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 10)
            .attr("width", 10)
            .attr("height", 10)
            .attr("fill", function(d,i) {return "#" + listColors[i];});



            legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", 22)
            .attr("y", 5)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d,i){ return listCharacters[i]});

            svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .call(legend)

        });
```

My issue is that I have two tooltips I would like to include, which draw from two separate subsections of the JSON.  The tooltips are defined by the following two var declarations:

```
            var tip = d3.tip()
            .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
            .offset([-10, 0])
            .html(function(d, i) {return console.log(d.line_text) + "<strong>(" + d.starting_line + ")</strong> <i>" + d.character + "</i>: " + d.line_text;});

            var stage_tip = d3.tip()
            .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
            .offset([-10, 0])
            .html(function(d, i) {return console.log(d.direction_text) + "<strong>(" + d.line_after + ") s.d.</strong> <i>" + d.direction_text;});
```

And declared within the two calls for the bars for items and directions:

```
    var stage_bars = svg.selectAll(".stage_bar")
        .data(directions)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "overlay")
        .attr("class", function(d, i) {return "stage_bar " + d.direction_text;})
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {return d.line_after;})
        .attr("width", 1)
        .attr("height", h)
        .style("fill", "black")
        .style("opacity",0.3)
        .call(stage_tip)
        .on('mouseover', stage_tip.show)
        .on('mouseout',stage_tip.hide);

    var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(items)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", function(d, i) {return "bar " + d.character;})
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {return d.starting_line;})
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {return y(d.location);})
        .attr("width", function(d, i) {return d.duration;})
        .attr("height", 15)
        .style("fill", function(d,i) {return "#" + d.color;})
        .call(tip)
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

My issue is that the tooltip for bars (the ones that call tip) works, but the tooltip for stage_bars (the ones that call stage-tip) does not. I think the issue is that I'm calling the same class in both tip and stage_tip, but declaring it as something other than tip makes no difference.

My question is how to get both tooltips functional.  Is this even possible?  I've seen examples that seem to do it but the code isn't clear.

Comment: Is that a third party plugin? If it's the one I think it is, it has to be `tip`. Why don't you create your own tooltips? It's easy and way more convenient to adapt in a situation like yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually really simple.  I had the stage_bars variable declared before the svg.append("rect") statements, which meant that the lines which indicates the stage directions were below the other objects.  So the mouse could never mouse over them to trigger the tooltip.  Moving the var declaration to a spot after those svg.append statements solved the issue.